# Show when element is found in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am creating a word search solver and used the `find()` method to detect when a value is inside an array.

The values of the table are placed in two arrays, one for rows, one for columns.

Right now, my program detects if a value is in the table or not.
**However, how could I highlight each value found in the table when the word is found?**

Code:

```js
//GENERATE TABLE
const table = document.querySelector('table');

function GenerateTable(x, y) {
  for (let column = 0; column < x; column++) {
    const newRow = table.insertRow();
    for (let row = 0; row < y; row++) {
      newRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createElement('INPUT'));
    }
  }
  let cells = document.querySelectorAll('td > input');
  for (const x of cells) {
    x.maxLength = 1;
    x.type = 'text';
    const index = [...cells].indexOf(x);
    x.onkeyup = function() {
      if (this.value != '' && cells[index + 1]) {
        cells[index + 1].focus();
      }
    }
  }
}

GenerateTable(5, 5)



//FIND WORDS
const input = document.getElementById('inputSearch');

function SubmitSearch() {
  console.clear();
  //Find Rows
  const arrayX = [];
  for (const row of table.rows) {
    for (const cell of row.cells) {
      const valueCell = cell.firstChild.value.toLowerCase();
      arrayX.push(valueCell)
    }
  }
  const values = chunkArray(arrayX, table.rows[0].cells.length);
  const valuesX = values.map(x => x.join(''));
  const foundX = valuesX.find(e => e.includes(input.value.toLowerCase()));

  //Find Columns
  const arrayY = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
    for (let b in values) {
      arrayY.push(values[b][a]);
    }
  }
  let valuesY = chunkArray(arrayY, table.rows[0].cells.length);
  valuesY = valuesY.map(x => x.join(''));
  const foundY = valuesY.find(e => e.includes(input.value.toLowerCase()));

  console.log(`Rows values: ${JSON.stringify(valuesX)}`);
  console.log(`Columns values: ${JSON.stringify(valuesY)}`);

  if (foundX || foundY) {
    console.log(`Word found!`);
  } else {
    console.log('Word not found')
  }
}

function chunkArray(x, chunk) {
  const array = [];
  while (x.length) {
    array.push(x.splice(0, chunk));
  }
  return array;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
<br>
<input type="text" id="inputSearch">
<button id="search" onclick="SubmitSearch()"> Find Words </button>
```

An example to illustrate my objective would be:

[image]

Thanks so much!

*Please note that diagonal and reversed search is not to be taken in consideration in my program*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking for the index of the arrays,

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the item if it finds it

[`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) returns the index if it finds it and -1 otherwise

Because of `Array` indexing you have to add 1 to the return value of [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

If the word was found on the column, the row wouldn't have the valid index and vice-versa.

So I used the index I got from the [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and used it get the word in that `row` or `column` then I used [`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to get the index from which the word that was found started from and returned that as the row (or column) number

```js
// I would advise you stop using inline event handlers (onevent)
const button = document.getElementById('search');
const table = document.querySelector('table');

function GenerateTable(x, y) {
  for (let column = 0; column < x; column++) {
    const newRow = table.insertRow();

    for (let row = 0; row < y; row++) {
      newRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createElement('INPUT'));
    }
  }

  let cells = document.querySelectorAll('td > input');

  for (const x of cells) {
    x.maxLength = 1;
    x.type = 'text';
    const index = [...cells].indexOf(x);
    x.onkeyup = function() {
      if (this.value != '' && cells[index + 1]) {
        cells[index + 1].focus();
      }
    }
  }
}

GenerateTable(5, 5)



//FIND WORDS
const input = document.getElementById('inputSearch');

function SubmitSearch() {
  console.clear();
  //Find Rows
  const arrayX = [];
  const searchWord = input.value.toLowerCase(); // We use this a lot so its best to store it in a value
  [...document.querySelectorAll('td.found')].forEach(cell => cell.classList.remove('found')); // To reset the styles for the cells

  for (const row of table.rows) {
    for (const cell of row.cells) {
      const valueCell = cell.firstChild.value.toLowerCase();
      arrayX.push(valueCell)
    }
  }

  const values = chunkArray(arrayX, table.rows[0].cells.length);
  const valuesX = values.map(x => x.join(''));
  let foundX = valuesX.findIndex(e => e.includes(searchWord));

  //Find Columns
  const arrayY = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
    for (let b in values) {
      arrayY.push(values[b][a]);
    }
  }
  let valuesY = chunkArray(arrayY, table.rows[0].cells.length);
  valuesY = valuesY.map(x => x.join(''));
  let foundY = -1;
  if (foundX < 0) foundY = valuesY.findIndex(e => e.includes(searchWord));

  console.log(`Rows values: ${JSON.stringify(valuesX)}`);
  console.log(`Columns values: ${JSON.stringify(valuesY)}`);

  if (foundY > -1 || -1 < foundX) {
    console.log(`Word found!`);

    if (foundX < 0) {
      foundX = valuesY[foundY].search(searchWord);

      // I got the rows and selected the rows the word were found in, then iterated through its children picking out the column to get its cell and added the class found with styling
      [...table.rows].slice(foundX, foundX + searchWord.length).forEach(row => row.children[foundY].classList.add('found'));
    }

    if (foundY < 0) {
      foundY = valuesX[foundX].search(searchWord);
      
      // I got the columns, then selected the particular row the word was found in, then iterated through its children and added the class found with styling
      [...table.rows[foundX].children].slice(foundY, foundY + searchWord.length).forEach(col => col.classList.add('found'));
    }
  } else console.log('Word not found');
}

function chunkArray(x, chunk) {
  const array = [];
  while (x.length) {
    array.push(x.splice(0, chunk));
  }
  return array;
}
```

```css
td.found {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

td.found input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
<br>
<input type="text" id="inputSearch">
<button id="search" onclick="SubmitSearch()"> Find Words </button>
```